# Gradle clean unable to delete dependent jar

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi-module Gradle 4.4 project - there's a parent `build.gradle` and then two child Gradle projects, each with their own `build.gradle`. Both are Java projects (one is for dev code, the other for QA). The dev project is a dependency of the QA project (I have `testCompile project(':dev-project')` in the QA project's `build.gradle`). Otherwise there is nothing remotely interesting or unusual in the `build.gradle` files - they import the `java` plugin and `com.github.johnrengelman.shadow`.

If I try to build the parent project twice in a row (no IDEs open, running `./gradlew clean build` from Git Bash without Administrator privileges), the build fails:

```
09:55:24.449 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Execute clean for :dev-project:clean'
09:55:24.449 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
09:55:24.450 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':dev-project:clean'
09:55:24.450 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] :dev-project:clean FAILED
09:55:24.451 [WARN] [org.gradle.api.Project] :dev-project:clean took 1587ms
09:55:24.451 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Task :dev-project:clean'
09:55:24.451 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Task :dev-project:clean' completed
09:55:24.452 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] :dev-project:clean (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 1.588 secs.
09:55:24.452 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Worker lease root.1.14 completed (1 worker(s) in use)
09:55:24.452 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Task worker for ':': released lock on root.1.14
09:55:24.452 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Task worker for ':': released lock on :
09:55:24.452 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]] finished, busy: 1.588 secs, idle:     0.002 secs
09:55:24.453 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 3,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs, idle:     1.59 secs
09:55:24.453 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs,     idle: 1.591 secs
09:55:24.454 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 3,5,main]] finished, busy: 0.0 secs,     idle: 1.592 secs
09:55:24.455 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Run tasks'
09:55:24.456 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:55:24.456 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
09:55:24.456 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:55:24.456 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
09:55:24.456 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task 'dev-project:clean'.
09:55:24.456 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Unable to delete file:     C:\workspace\parent-project\dev-project\libs\dev-project-0.1.0.jar
09:55:24.457 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:55:24.457 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
09:55:24.457 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with --scan to get full insights.
09:55:24.457 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
09:55:24.457 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
09:55:24.457 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task     ':dev-project:clean'.
09:55:24.457 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(    ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
09:55:24.457 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(    ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
09:55:24.458 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
09:55:24.458 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(    SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
```

I suspect that the `dev-project` JAR can't be deleted because it's depended on by the QA project, and so Gradle keeps some kind of lock on it.

I can build successfully if I delete the `Java(TM) Platform SE Binary` process in Windows Task Manager, but I'd like it to be automatic.

Comment: Hello, do you execute this command with Administrator permissions ?

Comment: No, it's on a work machine so admin access isn't possible.

Comment: _"[...] because generally, deletion commands should be executed in admin rights through IDE._ This is wrong, why do you say that?

Comment: Well, there must be a reason for the Java process to run. It could be another Gradle process or a `Test` / `JavaExec` task.

Comment: Try running: ```
gradle clean build --debug --full-stacktrace
``` to see if you can get a more detailed error message. Also [see](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows) if that JAR file is still in use by any processes and if it was, kill those processes.

Comment: Sohaieb, when you create a file, you become its owner and you can delete it. If you create a file as root, root becomes its owner and you can't delete it. To be more precise, whether you can or can't delete a file depends on its [permissions](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions).

Comment: Sadly without Admin privileges I can't run any of the solutions in the linked thread. As mentioned in the question, a Java process is holding onto the jar. It starts the first time I run `gradle clean build`, and doesn't disappear after the build finishes. I have pasted the debug logs into the question.

Comment: @Lukas Körfer the `build.gradle` is very plain, it uses the `java` plugin to run the build; there are no custom tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused by the Gradle Daemon - it stays running in the background after the build completes, and for some reason holds a lock on the `dev-project` jar.

Adding `org.gradle.daemon=false` to my global `gradle.properties` file has resolved the issue, albeit at the expense of marginally slower builds.

I have [raised an issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9572) with the Gradle team, and will update this answer if anything comes from it.